# how to get the total background color of td set to red using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I try to use the following code below to get the total number of td that are set to the background color of red but not working.

```
     $("#totalBackgroundTdRed").css("background","red").length;
```

The correct length should be 25 td who's background color are set to red but the above code is showing 1.

```
    $("#findRows").live("click", function(event)
    {
        var findArray = [];
        $(".findText").each(function()
        {   
           findArray.push($.trim($(this).text()));  
        });    

        var findArrayLength = findArray.length;
        var pattern = /^(?:[0-9]+\.\s+)?(.*):/;

        $("#logTable tr").find(".column2").each(function(event)
        {   
           var patternResults = pattern.exec($.trim($(this).text()));

           for(var i = 0; i < findArrayLength; i++)
           {            
              if(patternResults[1] == findArray[i])
              {
                 var $currentTR = $(this).closest("tr");
                 $currentTR.find(".inputTD").css("background","red");
                 $currentTR.find(".inputTD input").prop("checked", true);
              }
           }    
        });
           alert($("#totalBackgroundTdRed").css("background","red").length);
    });
```

Comment: you need to fine the td then get the length.i suggest add a class on the td that you put color red on as background then get the length of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

1) You have duplicate IDs for td elements i.e. `totalBackgroundTdRed`. IDs should be unique. you can rather use same value as classname and then use class selector to target them.

```
$(".totalBackgroundTdRed")
```

2) You need to use filter function to filter out elements based on condition:

```
 var columns = $('.totalBackgroundTdRed').filter(function(){
   var color = $(this).css("background-color").toLowerCase();
   return color === "#FF0000" || color === "rgb(255, 0, 0)" ;
 });
 alert(columns.length); // 25
```

Comment: Thanks Milind for leading me to a resolution and also refreshing my knowledge.

Comment: @BruceWalker: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use class instead of id,and logically you should follow @Milind answer which works perfectly.
Because Id is the attribute which should contain unique value in a page but you are assigning same id to many TD's hence better to use class in such cases.